# Get User control id within user control at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

is it possible to get the ID assigned to User Control from the control using javascript or jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What ASP.NET normally does is prefix your control's ID with a string that it uses to determine where in ASP.NET's control tree your actual control resides.

With that in mind, what I normally do is to use jQuery's 'ends with' selector to get the full ASP.NET-parsed ID at runtime.

Something like:

```
// get a handle on your original control
var myControl = $('[id$="<myOriginalId>"]');
// and then access it's properties
var myRuntimeId = myControl.eq(0).attr('id');
```

As you can most probably imagine, that's not going to cut it when you've got UserControls with the same ID used in different places of the form. I just jump in and put in some tweaks here and there (probably with using the `.eq()` function) to suit my business need.

Comment: thanks, this perfectly fits my situation with little modification :)

Answer (score 2):

You could put a class on the usercontrol, and then use something like $(".myUC").attr("id")

Comment: I do this too when I have to. I feel that I should note, however, that element classes are semantically designed to be used across multiple elements in your DOM, so something like this may return multiple elements in general. Well, either that or you're using the class name as an ID anyway.

Comment: I agree a degree of control needs to be applied with this route.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you to look at it from a different point of view:
In .Net you can get the generated ID by using `myControl.ClientID`.

If you put that in a javascript variable - I know it's not neat - you can then easily fetch it.

```
<!--mypage.aspx-->
<script>
  var myIdVar = "<%=myControl.ClientID%>";
  if(myIdVar == "foo")
  {
    alert("bar");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: this is the way to go, because it gets the exact ID without room for error